# V-for loop multidimensional call using vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I would like all the name and after this if parent is not null it should return parent.name

so data should be

```
Zack
Computer - mouse
Computer HDD
Laptop - Ram
```

How can i achieve this here is my code

```
    <li v-for="(index, item) in inventory">
       {{ item.name }}
    </li>
    <li v-for="par in item.parent"> {{ par.name }} </li>
  </ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L3gshbna/

This should return those parents is null and then whose parents are there see my expected response thanks

Comment: If there is going to be only one parent here is how you can do it https://jsfiddle.net/zxpkhsmd/, update your question if you want it to have multiple level of hierarchy.

Comment: This is correct but see my question This should return those parents is null and then whose parents are there see my expected response thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should sort your array first to achieve Zach as first output.
You can do it multiple ways, one of them you can see in my updated fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/doef2u01/1/

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-instance',
  data: {
    inventory: [
      {"id":21,"name":"Mouse","parent_id":3,"parent":{"id":3,"name":"Computer","parent_id":null}},
      {"id":1,"name":"Zack","parent_id":null, "parent":null},
      {"id":27,"name":"Ram","parent_id":4,"parent":{"id":4,"name":"Laptop","parent_id":null}},
      {"id":37,"name":"HDD","parent_id":6, "parent":{"id":6,"name":"Computer","parent_id":null}}
    ]
  },
  
  computed: {
      sortedInventory() {
     return [
       ...this.inventory.filter(item => item.parent === null),
        ...this.inventory.filter(item => item.parent !== null)
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue-instance">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(index, item) in sortedInventory">
       <template v-if="item.parent">
         {{item.parent.name}} -
       </template>
       {{ item.name }} 
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: that's fine thank you but 
Zack
Computer - mouse
Computer HDD
Laptop - Ram if computer has two items it should be also sorted

Comment: If you want to use current data structure then you need to GROUP your items by parent.name. You can use lodash for example.

If you are able to change data structure then consider output parents first with children array inside.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div id="vue-instance">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(index, item) in inventory">
       {{ item.name }}

    </li>
    <li v-for="par in inventory"> {{ par.parent.name }} </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: check this in jsfiddle and my question

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using v-if and v-else

```
<div id="vue-instance">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(i, value)  in inventory">
      <template v-if='value.parent'>
        {{value.parent.name}} - {{ value.name }}        
      </template>
      <template v-else>
        {{ value.name }}        
      </template>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: zack should come first whose parent does not exist first this came and parents data

Answer (score 0):

If I'm unterstanding you right this will give you the result:

```
<div id="vue-instance">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(index, item) in sorted">
      <span v-if="item.parent !== null"> {{ item.parent.name }} - </span>   {{ item.name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
  computed: {
        sorted: function() {
            return this.inventory.sort(item => {
                return item.parent_id !== null;
            });
        }
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e8z0gbkx/

Comment: Zack should come first whose parent does not exist first this came and parents data

Comment: You can archieve this by using `computed` properties. I updated my answer.

Comment: This is correct but it should sorted this way
Zack
Computer - mouse
Computer HDD
Laptop - Ram